# Data not emitted from child to parent component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Below are the child and parent components. I am not able to figure out where i am going wrong, but I am not able to pass value data from child to parent component. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Child Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn class="red-button" @click.prevent="checkAgent('information')">
      Information      
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="red-button" @click.prevent="checkAgent('policies')">
      Policies
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

  export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods: {
    checkAgent(value) {
      this.$emit('navigate', value);  
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Parent Component

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12 >
      <div class="account-section">
        <Details @navigate="moveTo(value)"/>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>          
</template>

<script>
  import Details from 'views/agent/edit.vue';
  

  export default {
    components: {
      Details,
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods: {
      moveTo(value) {
        console.log(value)
      },
    },
    
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be registering the `Details` component used in the parent template. Is that some typo?

Comment: @YomS. typo error. Please check now

Comment: @YomS.
In the moveTo method the value throws an error
Property or method "value" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the emitted event handler without specifying the parameter in the template  :

```
   <Details @navigate="moveTo"/>
```

method:

```
   methods: {
      moveTo(value) {
        console.log(value)
      },
    },
```

Comment: you're welcome and you must note that the value in the template is considered as undefined and passed again to the handler as undefined

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event), you can access **the emitted event’s value** with `$event`.

If the event handler is one method and without specifying any parameters, Vue will **pass the emitted value** as **the first parameter of that method**.

So for you codes,

**one fix** will be `<Details @navigate="moveTo($event)"/>`.

**another fix** will be `<Details @navigate="moveTo"/>` same as the answer of @Boussadjra Brahim .

Below is one simple demo for first fix:

```js
Vue.component('sidebar',{
    template:`
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="$emit('increment-btn', 1)">Increment on click</button>
        </div>
    `
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
      increment:0
  },
  methods: {
    getUpdated: function (newVal) {
      this.increment += newVal
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <sidebar v-on:increment-btn="getUpdated($event)"></sidebar>
            <p>{{ increment }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```